# How to show only some columns in Linked Access database

Tags: ms-access-2007, linked-tables

I have an access table called 'details' in database1 and I want to link it in another database 'database2'. I know how to create a linked table in database2 which reads in the data from database1 (from table 'details') but I only want to use some columns from 'details'. Is there a way to do this in Access????

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a linked table in database2 you can create a saved query in database2 that looks like this:

```
SELECT SomeField, SomeOtherField
FROM [;Database=C:\Users\Public\database1.accdb].details;
```